# Scala: Creating generic util with PureConfig

Tags: scala, pureconfig

I am looking for some utilities in scala which fit akka well that can map [HOCON](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md) to Scala class/object. (Something like `@Configuration` in Spring mapping the `.yml` or `.properties` file to Configuration bean/Java Class.)

What I tried with [PureConfig](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig) :

`spark.conf` config file in resources

```
spark{
    master {
        host = 1.2.3.4
        port = 7077
    }
}
```

Mapping to following scala classes :

```
trait Configuration {
    val nameSpace: String
}

case class SparkConfig(master: SparkMasterConfig) extends Configuration {
    override val nameSpace: String = "spark"
}

case class SparkMasterConfig(host: String,
                                    port: Int)
```

PureConfig works fine without generic:

```scala
import pureconfig.generic.auto._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

val conf = ConfigFactory.parseResources("spark.conf")
val sparkConfig = pureconfig.loadConfig[SparkConfig]("spark")

val config = sparkConfig match {
    case Left(f) => fail(f.toString)
    case Right(c) => c
}
```

However the following generic util doesn't even compile with `not enough arguments for method` [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiYcU.png)

```
object PureConfigLoader{
    def load[T <: Configuration](clazz: Class[T]): T = {
        val nameSpace = clazz.getField("nameSpace").get().asInstanceOf[String]

        import pureconfig.generic.auto._
        val configResult = pureconfig.loadConfig[T](nameSpace)  // this doesn't compile

        configResult match {
            case Right(x) => x.asInstanceOf[T]
            case Left(x) => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Fail to parse ${clazz.getSimpleName} from namespace $nameSpace")
        }
    }
}

val config = PureConfigLoader.load(classOf[SparkConfig])
```

My questions are:

1. What can I do with this generic PureConfig util?
2. `import pureconfig.generic.auto._` always marked as unused import by IntelliJ and it will be removed when formatting my code, how to fix this?
3. Are there any other config util/library works fine in similar way? I have also tried [circe-config](https://github.com/circe/circe-config) but still got similar issues. [Simple Scala Config](https://github.com/ElderResearch/ssc) uses Scala's Dynamic which is not good for refactoring like renaming the configuration property field.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a small wrapper of [Typesafe config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config):

**https://github.com/kxbmap/configs**

I tried your example - this compiles:

```
  object PureConfigLoader{
    def load[T <: MyConfig[T]](clazz: Class[T])(implicit A: Configs[T]): T = {
      val nameSpace = clazz.getField("nameSpace").get().asInstanceOf[String]

      val config = ConfigFactory.load("spark.conf")
        Configs[T].get(config, nameSpace) 
          .valueOrThrow(e=>
             new IllegalArgumentException(s"Fail to parse ${clazz.getSimpleName} from namespace $nameSpace: ${e.messages}" 
          )
      )
    }
  }

  val sparkConfig = PureConfigLoader.load(classOf[SparkConfig])

  abstract class MyConfig[T] (implicit A: Configs[T])

  case class SparkConfig() extends MyConfig[SparkConfig]
```

**Update**

I just saw in our code that you might **not** need this Util class at all! We use:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load("spark.conf")
val sparkConfig = Configs[SparkConfig].get(config, nameSpace)
```